# ODE -parabolic cylinder functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

How do we solve

$\frac{d^2f}{dz^2} + \left(Az^2+Bz+C\right)f=0 \tag 1$

where $f(z),A,B,C$ are matrices of order $3 \times 3$.